# Can't install Jython packages

Tags: pip, jython

I'm trying to install Jython swingutils, but I get the following error whenever I try to install any package using pip: "No module named _winreg"

I am using Windows 10, and use Eclipse as my IDE. My jython version is the latest, V2.7. Based on tons of google searches, it looks like I need to use an earlier version of PIP, but I don't know how to uninstall the version I have, and every set of instructions I found refer to linux.

So, do I need to manually uninstall the PIP I have and force install an earlier version? Or can I just install the swingutils package manually without PIP?

Comment: Are you actually on WIndows?

Comment: Yes, Windows 10.

Comment: Ok, I never did get PIP working with Jython, but I was able to install packages with the easy_installer. After navigating to "C:\jython2.7.3\bin", I could type "easy_install-2.7.exe jython-swingutils-2.1.2.tar.gz", and that worked.